# Question About Audio Device

Tags: audio, input

I have a USB audio device that has input and output from/to guitar. It gets power from USB. It was working all well before. But after recent updates, It's kind of half-working. The device only gets power when there is some audio is being playing in laptop or some input signal is sent from guitar. So, If I stop playing guitar for a second, it turns off and when I play again it goes on. I want to get continuous power. Is there any way I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems really simular:
https://superuser.com/questions/408683/why-my-usb-mouse-gets-suspended-after-3-seconds-of-inactivity

You can check if you have the same issue as the one above by entering the command:

```
for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/control; do echo on > $i; done
```

If this fixes your problem, you can make it permanent by editing `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf` in scratch

```
sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf
```

and replacing `CONTROL_USB_AUTOSUSPEND="auto"` by `CONTROL_USB_AUTOSUSPEND=0`

[Edit]

The permanent fix seems to have changed, if `modprobe usbcore autosuspend=-1` doesn't do anything, you need to change the bootloader.
To do this, you have to open the GRUB config in scratch.
`sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/default/grub` and loof for a line that states `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add `usbcore.autosuspend=-1` to that line.

The line will be something along the lines of this:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1"`

Comment: This command above with the for loop enabled power for my guitar. But I could not locate usb-audosuspend.conf file, because path doesn't exist. I have put that first command in a file, and run it when I need to use that device. Permanent fix would be awesome.

Comment: It might be in one of these files: `/etc/modprobe.conf`,
 `/etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf` or
`/etc/modprobe.d/options`. Look for `options usbcore autosuspend=1`

Comment: I have only /etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf file which has options in int. But there is no options for usbcore. Should I add options usbcore to this file or create a new file?

Comment: No you should not have to create those files. Does the command `modprobe usbcore autosuspend=-1` return anything?

Comment: It just executed without giving any error. Does this fixed the problem permanently?

Comment: Hmm. That should mean that one of the modprobe files should exist. Weird... I don't have time to look it up right now, but I will help you later. You could try the Grub thing if you want to.

Comment: I'm marking this answer solved for now. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @dg_no_9 No problem, I'm just a bit bussy today (deadlines ugh...) so I don't really have time right now. Will help you tomorrow :)

Comment: @dg_no_9 Accoarding to Google you need to open a configuration file in `/etc/modprobe.d` (there are multiple, just choose one) and add the line `options usbcore autosuspend=-1`. If that doesn't work you have to do what I said under the edit in my original post.